# .net core and ef core sql server error provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 8 - Protocol not supported

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I've been trying to develop a new application using .net core in MacOsX using a SQL Server database, but i'm having some problems with the connection because i'm getting the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HKTRSSNBPQOP": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 8 - Protocol not supported)

I'm using ef core to access the Data Base, the error stack is

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 8 - Protocol not supported)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
      ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 8 - Protocol not supported)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HKTRSSNBPQOP": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 8 - Protocol not supported)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at com.bloggin.controlers.BlogsController.Index() in /Users/darkgem/Documents/Trabajo/Profilling/Demo_Rule/Controllers/BlogsController.cs:line 17
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: How are you authenticating in your connection string? Are you using SQL Server Authentication or Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that the firewall on the Sql Server allows incoming connections on port 1433 and that Sql Server has TCP protocol enabled. [2005 link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712(v=vs.90).aspx) [2012 link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx)

**EDIT**

Network being roled out, it can be [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4234), that should be fixed, but still requires you to do and additional step. Please add `System.Net.Security` to your `project.json` file.

**EDIT**

Problem was in the connection string. Use a comma to specify a port number with SQL Server: mycomputer.test.xxx.com,1234

Comment: Hi, i know that there is no firewall rule that stops me to connect because i can use other SQL Managers like navicat or Aqua data studio to connect to it. Also  i just have confirm that the SQL Server hast TCP protocol enable, any more ideas?

Comment: Can you debug and get your actual connection string_?

Comment: i added System.Net.Security to your project.json and still have the problem. My connection string is: var connection = @"Data Source=server:port;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=Myuser;Password=myPass";

Comment: Use a comma to specify a port number with SQL Server:

mycomputer.test.xxx.com,1234

Comment: Adding a comma to the server name resolved my problem. It wasted my 5 hours :(. For e.g. "Server=SERVER01\\SQLSERVER,1433;Database=DBName;User Id=ABC; Password=IXYZ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"

Comment: To configure the port follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/57448109/9522887